# How do I make my speakers as an output on Arduino?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I want to use the readings off an LDR to dictate the sound. I know have to do this with a buzzer in my circuit and I know how to call my speakers in java, but I don't have any idea how to do this in Arduino.What I want exactly is something along the line of:
    input = analog read(pin 6);
    tone(LAPTOP SPEAKERS, input);

Answer (score 0):

So you want to use laptop to play music? them your arduino will send a messagge to the PC (by Serial, Bluethoot, Wifi, Ethernet, smoke signal) and a pc program will read that signal and play the according sound.

Or you can use the arduino with a buzzer, or with a speaker jack, and use the `tone()` function, or a mp3 shield if you need specific sound.

Answer (score 0):

You can send the readed value from pin6 over serial to pc , and use this value on java to generate a sound at this frequency. Send it over serial it's not a problem, it's so easy as Serial.print(input);, this will sent the readed value (0 - 255) to pc.

The main problem for me will be generate the tone at specific frequency on java, and it's not so hard.